# Fast, robust access to current files without cluttering the desktop (mac)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, file-management

In my workflow, I keep current files on the Desktop for ultra-fast access by mapping a keyboard shortcut to "show desktop".

Advantages:

- VERY fast.  Nothing is ever opened, the desktop is just shown
- Robust - this doesn't rely on a program that can be accidentally closed, etc.
- GUI: semi plus.  This helps with memory/recogntion, but mouse navigation is slower

Disadvantages:

- desktop looks ugly as heck, all cluttered

My question: **Is there a similar way to access a small number of files lightning fast without resulting in a cluttered desktop?**  Alternative workflow suggestions that achieve the same result also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: To close-voters: I think this is a legitimate question. It's not software-rec, it's not opinion based, it's not XY. It asks for a solution to an actual problem.

Comment: @gronostaj it's mostly opinion; _fast_,  _cluttered_ and _ugly_ are relative and subjective.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, saxdaddy, just read "dont want several icons on the desktop" where I've said the desktop looks "ugly" and "cluttered".  I've also described fast in an objective way: "keyboard shortcut" and "nothing is ever opened".  The question, as it stands, is not opinion based at all; I've merely inserted some opinions about my current setup.

Answer (score 1):

Two utilities I use for similar reasons [& have used for over 10 years, the first one since the 90's]

[DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/english/about.html)
Marketed as  Dock replacement, in fact it's just a fully-customisable set of 'containers' for anything you want to put in it - folders, apps, individual documents, text clippings...
Once there you can set a hot key to open/launch any item.
Visually, you can make it look pretty much exactly how you want it, lots of themes from plain to complex, & you can set it to park/hide anywhere.

[Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html)
A replacement file-picker dialog utility, customisable with different default sets & hot keys to go to specific locations.

I've used both of them for so long, I'm literally lost without them.

Comment: this is in line of what I was looking for - I'll check them out.  In the meantime, I think I'm just going to have a dedicated "current work" folder that I spill onto my desktop every time I want to get stuff done.  Thanks!